# Connect to the same database, but as a another user, without hardcoding a connection string

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Can I use `OPENDATASOURCE` (or another mechanism) from a Stored Procedure to connect to the same database as a different user? If so, how?

The database is meant to be deployed to several customers, and replicated by them as many times as they want to, etc. For this reason, I **CANNOT HARDCODE** the database server's name or the database's name.

(I tried using `OPENDATASOURCE`, but it only accepts hardcoded connection strings.)

Comment: Have you looked at setting up a Linked Server?

Comment: @JustinStolle: I don't know how to use Linked Servers.

Comment: I found this curious, i cant find any reason why a parameterized varchar as you showed code for shouldnt work. Actually i cant find any *definition* of this <whatever it is> anywhere! Only meantions Ole Db which i guess is the root of all evil here ;-) Good luck tho!

Comment: @stefan: Yeah, as the quality of Google searches increased in the early 2000s, the quality of MSDN documentation decreased.

Comment: @Eduardo i also tried the search in enterprise manager to no avail, very odd it just refuses to say what type it is so its impossible to say why it doesnt like the varchar parameter imo!

Comment: @stefan: I get the feeling that literal strings and `VARCHAR`s are different types. It just happens that a literal string may be assigned to a `VARCHAR` variable or field.

Comment: @Eduardo agreed. But i still wonder if this is by design or if it's any way to get around it :)

Comment: @stefan: It is probably by design. Otherwise, how do you assign string literals to `DATETIME`s, `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`s, etc?

Comment: @Eduardo i was referring to this specific function and why it needs a literal and not a varchar() (or any other text type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might `EXECUTE AS` work in your situation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx

Comment: I'll check. Still haven't read it all, but it seems like this is the answer.

Comment: The example code on that page looks quite useful. You'll have to grant impersonation rights to your users and then work out how to reliably `EXECUTE AS` another LOGIN (as opposed to another USER in the current database since you're going to access another database).

Comment: I don't want to grant impersonation rights. I want to log in as another user using his account name and password.

Comment: OK, you'd need to grant yourself impersonation rights for the other user(s) it sounds like. Example A on the MSDN page gives a good rundown.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Linked Server to connect to the remote server using the login's current security context (or other options as it applies to your situation).

From your stored procedure, you could access it with something like `SELECT * FROM mylinkedservername.mylinkedserverdatabase.dbo.mytable`

But you say you want to connect to the *same* database but using a different login? You're looking for impersonation. Perhaps you can do this making a Linked Server that references itself, I haven't tried it. Search Microsoft Help documentation for how to set it up normally and test if it does what you're looking to do.

Comment: I've been reading about Linked Servers, and now I'm thinking... is using a Linked Server to **the same database** really a good idea?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for impersonation. I am dealing with a stupid design that uses database users as application users, but the whole thing breaks when you want to work offline, and cannot afford to save passwords in memory (oh, noes, it is so totally not RESTful!).